# How to use RVIZ fixed frame to calculate object relative to the position of the robot

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Im currently using rviz to detect an object's relative position to robot. Any help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192158/how-to-use-rviz-fixed-frame-to-calculate-object-relative-to-the-position-of-the-robot/) by [Chirstina](https://answers.ros.org/users/20103/chirstina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-09-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rviz is a visualizer. It draws pretty pictures. For the most part, it doesn't do any processing of your data.

The proper tool to use here is [TF](http://wiki.ros.org/tf). If you have the position of a object in one frame, and your system knows the transformation between that frame and your robot's local frame, you can use TF to find the position of the object in your robot's local frame.

If you're unfamiliar with TF, the [TF Tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials) are a good place to start.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2